# Python Pandas - adding rows to an empty Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading this frame from file:

```
 df = pd.read_csv('playlist.csv')
```

and fetching all values under column `'track'`:

```
 tracks = df['track'].tolist()
```

then I have a `new_df` with the same order of columns as `'playlist.csv'`:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['artist','track', 'value'])
```

and, given `other_tracks = ['Once', 'Jeremy']`, I would to add the entire row of some tracks to the `new_df`

```
for track in tracks:
    if track in other_tracks:
         row = df[df['track']==track]
```

how do I do it?

is there a simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you don't need to loop, you can simply use boolean indexing:

```
new_df = df.loc[df['track'].isin(other_tracks)]
```

Comment: One thing to note here is that `tracks` should contain the filtered tracks only.

Comment: I've edited my question, because I need to use the condition. could you please contemplate it in your answer?

Comment: @outkast, i've edited my answer... Please try to provide sample and expected data sets when asking Pandas/Numpy/SKLearn/etc. - related questions